# Xcode 6 cannot archive getting an failed at exit code 1 message

Tags: xcode6

I'm new to making apps and I googled this error code but all the explanations for what to do were very confusing. I added a screenshot of my code can anyone explain simply what I did wrong and how to fix it? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste code here?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please visit [ask] question.

Comment: Are you using a beta build?